# How to Create Manifest file to manage Windows Nodes

Tags: puppet

I am new to Puppet and so I am totally confused about how to create a Manifest that can deploy any application on Windows Nodes. I have successfully configured the Open-source Puppet Server on Centos 7 Machine and I am using Windows 10 machine as a Puppet Client. I am also done with the certificate exchange between Server and Client.
So can you please suggest me some point so that I can create my manifest file to manage the windows Nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to start writing a new module is to use the [pdk](https://puppet.com/docs/pdk/1.x/pdk.html). It runs on Windows, Mac and Linux.
If you're on Windows then in powershell you'd run `pdk new module <module name>` and then `cd <module name>` and `pdk new class <module name>` . That will give you the basic construction of a module that you can push up to your git repo. It also contains an rspec testing framework etc.

The [Puppet forge](https://forge.puppet.com/) has some great examples of code.

You probably want to look at using [Chocolatey](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/chocolatey) it's a package manager similar to Yum.

Some example code for your manifest, in /manifests/init.pp

```
class <module name> {
  require chocolatey # forge module
  Package { provider => chocolatey, }

  package { 'git':
    ensure => installed,
  }

  user { 'testuser':
    ensure  => present,
    groups  => 'testgroup',
    comment => 'Test user',
  }

  file { 'C:\Program Files\testuser':
    ensure => directory,
    owner  => 'testuser',
    group  => 'testgroup', 
  }

  acl { 'C:\Program Files\testuser':
    permissions => [
      { identity => 'testuser', rights => ['full']},
      { identity => 'testgroup', rights => ['read']}
    ],
  }
}
```